# vb.net overload resolution failed for find/replace search

Tags: vb.net, function, replace, find

```
Public Sub MyFunction()
    Dim lowstring As String
    lowstring = "hi"
    Me.RichTextView.Find(lowstring, 0, 2)
End Sub
```

The above produces the error of

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible `'Find'` can be called without a narrowing conversion:
>
> ---
>
> > ```
> > Public Function Find(characterSet() As Char, 
> >     start As Integer, end As Integer) As Integer:
> > ```
> >
> > Argument matching parameter `'characterSet'` narrows 
> >         from `'String'` to `'1-dimensional array of Char'`.
> >
> > ---
> >
> > ```
> > Public Function Find(str As String, start As Integer, 
> >     options As System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxFinds) As Integer:
> > ```
> >
> > Argument matching parameter `'options'` narrows from `'Integer'` to 
> >         `'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxFinds'`.

The error doesn't occur if you change the replacement string value, only if you change the second or third values to something other than `0`.

Why doesn't the use of standard integers work here?  What does this error really mean?  Can anyone point me to some documentation for handling overloaded functions in vb.net (2010)?

I hope this question is focused enough... I've just been pretty confused about this one.

Thanks for any help - EB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see, [`RichTextBox.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.find.aspx) has 7 overloads.
The one you're calling with 3 arguments and two integers takes a `Char[]` as first parameter, not a `String`.

This overload is used when you want to find *the first instance of a character from a list of characters.*

I assume that you want to find the position of your `string` in a given range. Then you need to use this overload: [`RichTextBox.Find`(String, Int32, Int32, RichTextBoxFinds)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab8wkhy.aspx).

For example:

```
' Obtain the location of the search string in RichTextView'
Dim index = RichTextView.Find(lowstring, 0, 2, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord)
```

Note that you can combine different [`RichTextBoxFinds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextboxfinds.aspx)  bitwise.

For example:

```
Dim index = Me.RichTextView.Find(
        lowstring,
        0,
        2,
        RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord Or RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function call does not match any of the overloads exactly. However, VB was kind enough to find two possible matches that would work if an argument you provided was casted to a different type.

You probably wanted the overload with the `string` parameter. So you should have written,

```
RichTextBox1.Find(lowstring, 0, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord)
```

The fact that `RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord` happens to have numeric value of `2` is not a reason to use that value instead of the enum member name.

This would also work:

```
RichTextBox1.Find(lowstring, 0, CType(2, RichTextBoxFinds))
```

but it is stupid.